# tkinter image not loading, tclerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

I'll try to explain this to my best ability. Short story short, making a tic tac toe game for a school project. I have all the code necessary i think, but when i run my code, tkinter window opens no problem, but when i am to click in one of the squares where i can place a "x" or a "o" my image wont load into the grid.

When i click, this is one the errors that pops up:
line 2776, in _create
return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "562.5"

If i was to guess, the error must be in both "def draw_o" and "def draw_x"

If you want to try the code here is the images to download: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW9Bp.jpg

If relevant image of assignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lewRP.jpg

```
from math import log
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

size = 600
symbol_size = (size / 3 - size / 8) /2
symbol_thick = 50
symbol_x_color = '#EE4035'
symbol_o_color = '#0492CF'
green = '#7BC043'



class cell:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Bondesjakk/Tic Tac Toe")
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width = size, height = size)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.window.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)

        

        self.initialize_board()
        self.player_x_turns = True
        self.board_status = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3) )

        self.player_x_starts = True
        self.reset_board = False
        self.gameover = False
        self.tie = False
        self.x_wins = False
        self.o_wins = False

        self.x_score = False
        self.o_score = False
        self.tie_score = False

        
    
    def mainloop(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def initialize_board(self):
        for i in range(2):
            self.canvas.create_line( (i + 1) * size / 3, 0, (i + 1) * size / 3, size)
        
        for i in range(2):
            self.canvas.create_line(0, (i + 1) * size / 3, size, (i + 1) * size / 3)

    def play_again(self):
        self.initialize_board()
        self.player_x_starts = not self.player_x_starts
        self.player_x_turns = self.player_x_starts
        self.board_status = np.zeros(shape =(3, 3) )

    def draw_o(self, logical_pos):
        o_image = PhotoImage('book/pybook/image/o.gif')
        logical_pos = np.array(logical_pos)
        grid_pos = self.convert_logical_to_grid_pos(logical_pos)
        self.canvas.create_image(grid_pos[0] - symbol_size, grid_pos[1] - symbol_size,
                                 grid_pos[0] + symbol_size, grid_pos[1] + symbol_size, width = symbol_thick,
                                 image = o_image)
    
    def draw_x(self, logical_pos):
        x_image = PhotoImage('book/pybook/image/x.gif') 
        grid_pos = self.convert_logical_to_grid_pos(logical_pos)
        self.canvas.create_image(grid_pos[0] - symbol_size, grid_pos[1] - symbol_size,
                                 grid_pos[0] + symbol_size, grid_pos[1] + symbol_size, width = symbol_thick,
                                 image = x_image)
    
    def display_gameover(self):

        if self.x_wins:
            self.x_score += 1
            text = "Winner: Player 1(x)"
            color = symbol_x_color

        elif self.o_wins:
            self.o_score += 1
            text = "Winner: Player 2(o)"
            color = symbol_o_color
        
        else:
            self.tie_score += 1
            text = "It's a tie"
            color = "gray"

        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.canvas.create_text(size / 2, size / 3, font = "cmr 60 bold", fill = color, text = text)

        score_text = 'Scores \n'
        self.canvas.create_text(size / 2, 5 * size / 8, font = "cmr 40 bold", fill = green, text = score_text)

        score_text = 'Player 1 (x) : ' + str(self.x_score) + '\n'
        score_text = 'Player 2 (o) : ' + str(self.o_score) + '\n'
        score_text = 'Tie          : ' + str(self.tie_score) + '\n'

        self.canvas.create_text(size / 2, 3 * size / 4, font = "cmr 30 bold", fill = green, text = score_text)

        self.reset_board = True

        score_text = "Click to play again \n"
        self.canvas.create_text(size / 2, 15* size / 16, font = "cmr 20 bold", fill = "gray", text = score_text)

    def convert_logical_to_grid_pos(self, logical_pos):
        logical_pos = np.array(logical_pos, dtype = int)
        return (size / 3) * logical_pos + size / 6
    
    def convert_grid_to_logical_pos(self, grid_pos):
        grid_pos = np.array(grid_pos)
        return np.array(grid_pos // (size / 3), dtype = int)
    
    def is_grid_occupied(self, logical_pos):
        if self.board_status[logical_pos[0] ][logical_pos[1] ] == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    
    def is_winner(self, player):
        player = -1 if player == "x" else 1

        #Three in a row
        for i in range(3):
            if self.board_status[i][1] == self.board_status[i][2] == player:
                return True
            if self.board_status[0][1] == self.board_status[2][i] == player:
                return True
        
        #Diagonals
        if self.board_status[0][0] == self.board_status[1][1] == self.board_status[2][2] == player:
            return True
        if self.board_status[2][0] == self.board_status[1][1] == self.board_status[0][2] == player:
            return True

        return False
    
    def is_tie(self):
        r, c = np.where(self.board_status == 0)
        tie = False
        if len(r) == 0:
            tie = True
        
        return tie

    def is_gameover(self):
        self.x_wins = self.is_winner("x")
        if not self.x_wins:
            self.o_wins = self.is_winner("o")

        if not self.o_wins:
            self.tie = self.is_tie()
        
        gameover = self.x.wins or self.o.wins or self.tie

        if self.x_wins:
            print("x wins!")
        if self.o_wins:
            print("o wins!")
        if self.tie:
            print("It's a tie!")
        
        return gameover
    
    def click(self, event):
        grid_pos = [event.x, event.y]
        logical_pos = self.convert_grid_to_logical_pos(grid_pos)

        if not self.reset_board:
            if self.player_x_turns:
                if not self.is_grid_occupied(logical_pos):
                    self.draw_x(logical_pos)
                    self.board_status[logical_pos[0] ][logical_pos[1] ] = -1
                    self.player_x_turns = not self.player_x_turns
            
            else:
                if not self.is_grid_occupied(logical_pos):
                    self.draw_o(logical_pos)
                    self.board_status[logical_pos[0] ][logical_pos[1] ] = 1
                    self.player_x_turns = not self.player_x_turns
            
            if self.gameover():
                self.display_gameover()
        else:
            self.canvas.delete("all")
            self.play_again()
            self.reset_board = False

game_instance = cell()
game_instance.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provide a [mre]. Much easier to figure out the problem if there are as few lines of code as possible

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: full error message should show you in which line you have problem and first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. It seems you have wrong value in some variable or use it in wrong way. It show problem with option `"562.5"` - so maybe instead of `var="562.5"` it gets something like `"562.5"=var`

Answer (score 1):

In `create_image()` you use `x1, y1, x2, y2, width=...` but it expects only position `(x1,y1)` as tuple (without `x2,y2`) and without `width=...`

```
        x = grid_pos[0] - symbol_size
        y = grid_pos[1] - symbol_size
        self.canvas.create_image( (x, y), image=x_image)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You have other mistakes

In line `if self.gameover()` you have to remove `()`

--

If you use `PhotoImage('book/pybook/image/o.gif')` then it treats it as string with image's data, not as path to file. You have to use `file=`

```
o_image =  PhotoImage(file='book/pybook/image/o.gif')
```

--

But there is another problem. There is bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable in function. You should assign to class variable using `self.`

```
self.o_image =  PhotoImage(file='book/pybook/image/o.gif')
```

--

And here another problem. You load the same image  again and again and you assign it to the same variable - so `bug` removes previous image from memory and it removes it from `canvas`.

You could load it only once in `__init__` and later use all time the same `self.o_image`, `self.x_image`

```
def __init___(...):

    self.o_image =  PhotoImage(file='book/pybook/image/o.gif')
    self.x_image =  PhotoImage(file='book/pybook/image/x.gif')
```

---

Doc (`effbot.org` in `archive.org`): [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20200313162612/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm), [Canvas](https://web.archive.org/web/20200313162549/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)